# Bit-wise shift for Matrix iteration?

Tags: c++, matrix, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

### Ok some background

I have been working on this project, which I had started back in college, (no longer in school but want to expand on it to help me improve my understanding of C++). I digress... The problem is to find the Best path through a matrix. I generate a matrix filled with a set integer value lets say 9. I then create a path along the outer edge (Row 0, Col length-1) so that all values along it are 1.

The goal is that my program will run through all the possible paths and determine the best path. To simplify the problem I decide to just calculate the path SUM and then compare that to what the SUM computed by the application.

[image]

(The title is miss leading S=single-thread P=multi-threads)

### OK so to my question.

In one section the algorithm does some simple bit-wise shifts to come up with the bounds for iteration. My question is how exactly do these shifts work so that the entire matrix (or MxN array) is completely traversed?

```
void AltitudeMapPath::bestPath(unsigned int threadCount, unsigned int threadIndex) {
    unsigned int tempPathCode;
    unsigned int toPathSum, toRow, toCol;
    unsigned int fromPathSum, fromRow, fromCol;

    Coordinates startCoord, endCoord, toCoord, fromCoord;

    // To and From split matrix in half along the diagonal
    unsigned int currentPathCode = threadIndex;
    unsigned int maxPathCode = ((unsigned int)1 << (numRows - 1));
    while (currentPathCode < maxPathCode) {
        tempPathCode = currentPathCode;

        // Setup to path iteration
        startCoord = pathedMap(0, 0);
        toPathSum = startCoord.z;
        toRow = 0;
        toCol = 0;

        // Setup from path iteration 
        endCoord = pathedMap(numRows - 1, numCols - 1);
        fromPathSum = endCoord.z;
        fromRow = numRows - 1;
        fromCol = numCols - 1;

        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < numRows - 1; index++) {
            if (tempPathCode % 2 == 0) {
                toCol++;
                fromCol--;
            }
            else {
                toRow++;
                fromRow--;
            }
            toCoord = pathedMap(toRow, toCol);
            toPathSum += toCoord.z;
            fromCoord = pathedMap(fromRow, fromCol);
            fromPathSum += fromCoord.z;
            tempPathCode = tempPathCode >> 1;
        }

        if (toPathSum < bestToPathSum[threadIndex][toRow]) {
            bestToPathSum[threadIndex][toRow] = toPathSum;
            bestToPathCode[threadIndex][toRow] = currentPathCode;
        }

        if (fromPathSum < bestFromPathSum[threadIndex][fromRow]) {
            bestFromPathSum[threadIndex][fromRow] = fromPathSum;
            bestFromPathCode[threadIndex][fromRow] = currentPathCode;
        }
        currentPathCode += threadCount;
    }
}
```

I simplified the code since all the extra stuff just detracts from the question. Also if people are wondering I wrote most of the application but this idea of using the bit-wise operators was given to me by my past instructor.

#### Edit:

I added the entire algorithm for which each thread executes on. The entire project is still a work a progress but here is the source code for the whole thing if any one is interested [[GITHUB]](https://github.com/pixeloven/ShortestPath)

Comment: `tempPathCode = tempPathCode >> 1;` is an obfuscated way of writing `tempPathCode /= 2;`, and `((unsigned int)1 << (numRows - 1));` means `2` to the power of `numRows - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A right bit shift is equivalent to dividing by 2 to the power of the number of bits shifted. IE 1 >> 2 = 1 / (2 ^ 2) = 1 / 4

A left bit shift is equivalent to multiplying by 2 to the power of the number of bits shifted. IE 1 << 2 = 1 * 2 ^ 2 = 1 * 4

I'm not entirely sure what that algorithm does and why it needs to multiply by 2^ (num rows - 1) and then progressively divide by 2.

Comment: Alright that helps clear up what the bit shifts are doing. Now I am just curious as to how that allows for the complete analysis of every potential path in the matrix. Because if I am not mistaken the number of paths in a matrix can be calculated by (m-1 + n-1)!/((m-1)!(n-1)!) and these loops don't seem to approach anywhere near the numbers I calculated.

Comment: @ductiletoaster I suspect you have removed important parts of the algorithm, as it doesn't seem to be calculating anything.

Comment: That is correct. I was attempting to simplify the example to just the core part of the problem but it appears I oversimplified. Ill edit my question to provide more details.

Comment: I added some more details to my question but I also have to step away for a while so if I don't get any more response by the time I return I'll make sure to give you credit for the answer since you did help to clarify the bit-shift aspect.